# Styling bug that switched form field orders

Tags: html, css, styling

I have had the same login form and create_profile form for a long time.  Yesterday some style changes were made on the site and today to my amazement, these two forms have fields reversed.

Here is the example of what I am talking about:
http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com/create_profile.php

I am not very knowledgeable in CSS issues, and I have never seen something like this. Any idea what may be causing this?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What specifically is the issue with that page? I see all of the inputs labeled appropriately with their <label> elements, no mix ups there...

Comment: To me, on FF and Chrome, the Field names show up all the way on the right.  While the places where you are supposed to write stuff are all the way on the left.  It doesn't show up for you like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`label span` has been floated right in your CSS:

```
label span {
  float: right;
  width: 15em;
}
```

Change it to:

```
label span {
  float: left;
  width: 15em;
}
```

Comment: That totally solved it.  You saved me from a lot of panic - thank you :)